# How delete many-to-many relation in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a problem with the removal of items from the database if connects them a many to many relationship

My database look like

```
| [Project] | <-- | [JobInProject] | --> | [Job] |
=============     ==================     =========
| ProjectID |     | JobInProjectID |     | JobID |
|           |     | ProjectID      |     |       |
|           |     | JobID          |     |       |
```

Primary keys from `Project` and `Job` table are also set as foreign key in others tables but I think it isn't problem because when I remove item from `Job` table, it is removed correctly with all related items in others tables

All foreign keys are set by constraint and on delete cascade on update cascade

Code which I use to delete job item

```
 Job job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(id);
 db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Deleted;
 await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and project:

```
Project project = await db.Projects.FindAsync(id);
db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Deleted;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Code to remove project item remove only data from `Project` table and `JobInProject` table do not remove `Job` and related items.

When I modify code to remove `Project` like this:

```
 Project project = await db.Projects.FindAsync(id);

 foreach (var item in project.JobInProjects)
 {
     db.Entry(item.Job).State = EntityState.Deleted;
 }

 db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Deleted;
 await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get an error on the `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` line

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

How can I remove `Project` item and related `Job` items ?

I will be grateful for help

Comment: `Primary keys from Project and Job table are also set as foreign key in others tables`, how can you have *a single* foreign key to the other entity in a many-to-many relation? This implies you have one-to-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't mark the `JobInProject` object as `Deleted`:

```
foreach (var item in project.JobInProjects)
{
    db.Entry(item.Job).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted; // <= line added
}
```

If you don't do that, EF will assume you don't want to delete the item and try to set both foreign keys in `JobInProject` to `null`, but of course *one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable* (both aren't).