# Entity Framework Many to Many relationship leaves data in joining table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have attempted a Many-to-Many relationship using Entity Framework Code First.

The objects are `CARD` and `USER_LIST`; a `CARD` can have many `USER_LIST` assigned to it and a single `USER_LIST` can be assigned to many `CARD`.

The classes are defined as follows:

```
public partial class CARD : DBEntityItem {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CARD_ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string SHORT_DESC { get; set; }

        public int STAGE_ID { get; set; }

        public int GROUP_ID { get; set; }

        public int FLAGS { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string OFFICE_APP_REF { get; set; }

        [StringLength(7)]
        public string CARD_COLOUR { get; set; }

        public int CTYPE_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual GROUP GROUP { get; set; }

        public virtual CARD_TYPE CARD_TYPE { get; set; }

        public virtual STAGE STAGE { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<USER_LIST> USER_LIST { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public CardFlags FlagOptions { get; set; }

        public enum CardFlags {
            None = 0,
            Blocked = 1,
            Unexpected = 2,
            Emergency = 4,
            Failed = 8
        }

        public CARD()
            : base("CARD", "CARD_ID") {
            USER_LIST = new HashSet<USER_LIST>();
        }
    }

public partial class USER_LIST : DBEntityItem {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int USER_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string USER_NAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PREFERENCE_VALUE> PREFERENCE_VALUE { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<USER_PERMISSIONS> USER_PERMISSIONS { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<USER_TASK> USER_TASK { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CARD> CARD { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CHANGE_NOTE> CHANGE_NOTE { get; set; }

    public USER_LIST()
        : base("USER_LIST", "USER_ID") {
        PREFERENCE_VALUE = new HashSet<PREFERENCE_VALUE>();
        USER_PERMISSIONS = new HashSet<USER_PERMISSIONS>();
        USER_TASK = new HashSet<USER_TASK>();
        CARD = new HashSet<CARD>();
    }
}
```

Ignore the inheritance from `DBEntityItem` and the resulting constructor chain as that is simply a class that is used to give the Entities some additional functionality.

The Many-to-Many mapping is defined within `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CARD>()
    .HasMany(e => e.USER_LIST)
    .WithMany(e => e.CARD)
    .Map(m => {
        m.MapLeftKey("CARD_ID");
        m.MapRightKey("USER_ID");
        m.ToTable("CARDUSER");
        });
```

This is due to 'CARDUSER' being an existing table in the database.

A `List<USER_LIST>` is built up and is set as the `USER_LIST` property against a `CARD` object. When calling `SaveChanges()`, this results in the following (as expected):

```
MyCardObject.USER_LIST = MyListOfUsers;
MyDBContext.SaveChanges();
```

[image: CARDUSER table data]

As can be seen, the correct entries have been inserted into the CARDUSER table as required.

The issue I have arises when I try to delete the CARD:

```
MyDBContext.CARD.Remove(MyCardObject);
MyDBContext.SaveChanges();
```

The above will remove the CARD record from the CARD table; however, all of the records pertaining to this CARD within CARDUSER are still there:

[image: There is nothing in the CARD table but CARDUSER still contains data]

I came across the following question and had hoped that this would answer my question:

[How delete many-to-many relation in Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218551/how-delete-many-to-many-relation-in-entity-framework-6)

However, I have defined the Many-to-Many mapping within the DBContext without the need to explicitly define a `CARDUSER` object and I therefore cannot set the `State` against each `CARDUSER` object to `Deleted`.

Why is it that this data is hanging around in the CARDUSER table and how can this be set up so that both the CARD_ID and USER_ID fields within CARDUSER are proper, enforced Foreign Key values? I have tried setting Foreign Key constraints on the CARDUSER table within the database itself; however, if I do that, then when I set the `USER_LIST` property against the `CARD` object and then try to save the changes, it results in a Foreign Key Violation within `CARDUSER`, with the system attempting to re-insert all of the entries that were already set against the `CARD`.

Comment: Looks like you have removed `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`.

Answer (score 0):

In a Many-to-Many Relationship you must have a junction/bridge table.
You can see in the link that you posted, he has a junction table.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track when you added a foreign key constraint to the join table.  SQL Server (by default) will not `cascade` a deletion through foreign key relationships, which is why you (rightfully) receive an error.  If you define the foreign keys as `on delete cascade` you will get the behavior you want.

Alternatively, you can define the foreign key without the cascade behavior.  If you do that, you've got to make sure you delete the entries in the join table manually.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I can see where you're coming from; however, from my perspective, it shouldn't be necessary for me to define the cascade delete in the DB; you should be able to define that as part of the model in the code. However, I don't have the 'WillCascaseOnDelete' option when I define the Many-to-Many mapping that I have in onModelCreating. For now, I'm deleting the entries in the Join Table manually; however, I still don't understand why I can't, in code, structure it such that when I remove a CARD object, that it knows it also needs to remove the CARDUSER records as well.